# Error in Shapiro test for multiple variables:

Tags: r

I am having a strange problem when doing Shapiro test for multiple variables. It works fine is I have one variable.
But in multiple it says error.
e.g. with the iris data:

```
library(magrittr)
iris %>% head()
iris %>% shapiro.test(Sepal.Length, Petal.Width)

> iris %>% shapiro.test(Sepal.Length, Petal.Width)
Error in shapiro.test(., Sepal.Length, Petal.Width) : 
  unused arguments (Sepal.Length, Petal.Width)
```

Also if I want to do for whole data

```
for(i in seq(dim(iris)[2])) {
  result <- append(result, shapiro.test(data[[i]]))
}
```

Again error

```
Error in data[[i]] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
```

Can anyone please help me to know what might be the problem.
Thanks a lot in advance.
Regards,
Mitra

Comment: `shapiro.test()` is for one variable not two.Run this `?shapiro.test()` and read documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `lapply` to apply the test on numeric variables.

```
cols <- sapply(iris, is.numeric)
result <- lapply(iris[cols], shapiro.test)
result
```

Answer (score 0):

With `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
iris %>%
       summarise(across(where(is.numeric), ~ list(shapiro.test(.))))
```